# How do you display the same screen on differnt monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm doing a little hobby project and I'm trying to think of a way to have 4 lcd monitors display my screen using one dvi port.

Also would I have to make my own driver for said project?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it on one dvi port without adding some hardware.

Try shopping for some of [these splitter solutions.](http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&source=hp&q=4-way+dvi+splitter)

Unfortunately, for a 4-way split, the solution will have to be a powered unit because of the loss of quality by splitting 4-ways.

Comment: I agree - this is the only practical solution that would meet his requirements (one DVI port driving 4 monitors.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this

The first is to buy an additional graphics card - for 4 monitors, you will most likely need 2 adapters with 2x DVI/VGA ports (or use adapters) on each, then simply plug all together and use "Mirror" mode so that all monitors show the same.

However, I would personally go for a splitter, either VGA or DVI, then you will only need one graphics card.

Comment: Note that the majority of contemporary graphics cards issued nowadays do have 2 DVI/VGA ports.